# Is there a minimum current drain to use LM25011 of TI?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

Using LM25011 as switching voltage regulator to power a board with wide range of current drain rates.

- Input of 24v;
- Output of 5V;
- Drain current between 5mA and 1A.

Is this component suitable to this purposes?

I'm asking this becouse I'd like to use this module to power also another device with a 10mA drain at 5v. On datasheet I see that efficiency drastically go down at 300mA and no information on less than this value.

Additional question, is this IC able to operate under 300mA load, so at 10mA?

Comment: There's this WEBENCH tool ( http://www.ti.com/webench ) mentioned in the datasheet, have you tried it? You will be hard pressed to find a DCDC converter that has good (what is good?) efficiency for Iload = 5 mA to 1 A. Consider that the DCDC converter itself consumes 50 mA, what does that mean for efficiency at Iload = 5 mA and Iload = 1 A? A DCDC converter that cannot function properly without a load connected (Iload = 0 mA) would be **silly** if you ask me.

Comment: I've tried and by values seems working. I don't understand why this is silly. If I've a board,with some parameters unknown because a multitude of reasons, but efficiency is not a goal, I should try to make it works with simplest solution. I.E. If I have 24v-5v regulation and I must power a micro at 20mA and 1A LEDs load, when LEDs are off, this DCDC will still power my micro without problems? This is a single example of what I mean wide operation.

Comment: *I don't understand why this is silly.* OK, suppose you sell DCDC converter modules. Yours can only work when there is a load of at least 1 mA. With no load they overheat and get damaged. Would I buy your DCDC converters or would I go to the next guy who has DCDC converters that work fine when no load is connected?

Comment: That's right, but in this case I'm not going to build a DCDC converter. I'm looking for a DCDC component suitable for both operations to keep cost low. Since this component is not advice, what do you suggest as solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular part is recommended to have a minimum of about 1mA output current because of considerations regarding the boostrap capacitor charge. You can select the feedback resistor values to guarantee that current. See 7.3.5. Efficiency will be miserable, of course, at low currents.

> The LM25011 integrates an N-Channel buck switch and associated floating high-voltage gate driver. The gate
>   driver circuit works in conjunction with an external bootstrap capacitor (CBST) and an internal high-voltage diode.
>   A 0.1-µF capacitor connected between BST and SW provides the supply voltage for the driver during the ontime. During each off-time, the SW pin is at approximately –1 V, and CBST is recharged from the internal 5-V
>   regulator for the next on-time. The minimum off-time ensures a sufficient time each cycle to recharge the
>   bootstrap capacitor.
>   In applications with relatively high output voltage and low minimum load current, the internal pre-charge device of
>   the LM25011 may not pull the SW pin sufficiently low during the off-time to maintain the voltage on the bootstrap
>   capacitor. If the bootstrap capacitor (CBST) discharges during the long off-times, and the regulator will cycle on
>   and off at a low frequency. Decreasing the values of the feedback resistors RFB1 and RFB2 to provide a minimum
>   load of typically 1mA at nominal VOUT will increase the minimum switching frequency and maintain sufficient
>   bootstrap capacitor voltage.

If you want high efficiency at low load currents as well as high load currents (for example, for battery operation with intermittent high current draw) you could consider something like an [LT8608](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/lt8608.pdf) which will operate with better than 75% efficiency above 1mA or so, and 60% at 100uA. This is done by introducing burst mode operation at low currents, as well as designing the part to have a very low quiescent current.

Of course that wonderfulness comes at a price, about double the cost for the chip in 1K quantity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Very good alternative but very expensive. There're also cheaper alternatives?

Comment: @Singed you should shop around for the best solution to your problem. Many makers offer parametric search engines that you should use.